# Is there an Ubuntu One server in South Africa?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, streaming

I would like to know if UbuntuOne has server locally in South Africa? I currenly use dropbox, but due to bandwidht speeds the sync speed is not what it should be. It would be great if theres a local server(s) to handle file sync and streaming audio.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is no U1 server in South Africa.

You can look at the source code in the `python-ubuntuone-client` package to see that it connects to the host `fs-1.one.ubuntu.com`.  That may have geodns magic, but for me it resolves to `91.189.89.76` which mtr and other tools show is located in the UK.

(It's possible the client later connects elsewhere, but I'm pretty sure not.)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One is currently (AFAIK) based off Amazon's S3 storage service. Amazon have [a section about the regions they offer](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Where_is_my_data_stored) in their S3 FAQ:

> Amazon S3 offers storage in the US Standard, EU (Ireland), US West (Northern California), Asia Pacific (Singapore), and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Regions. You specify a Region when you create your Amazon S3 bucket.

So nothing anywhere near Africa.

I should point out that while U1 *could* provision the nearest storage to you, it's more likely that everybody gets put in the same place. Backup storage isn't really a latency-sensitive thing so I'd imagine Ubuntu use whatever is most convenient and/or cheapest for them.

... But I'd wait for somebody from Canonical to comment on that before you take it as fact.

Comment: File sync and especially music streaming are latency and jitter sensitive, as users would prefer the music start sooner than later, and not drop out.  Also, if SA's internationaly connections are overloaded (I don't know if that's true) then both of them may perform poorly.

Comment: In neither of those services does the U1 client connect directly to S3 (if S3 is used at all), so even if there was an S3 AZ is Africa it would not matter.  The question is where the front end server is.